# Using grep or other command to return the line number of a multiline pattern

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep, less-unix

I was using the `less` command to browse a very huge text log file (15 GB) and was trying to search for a multiline pattern but after some investigation, `less` command can only search single line patterns.

Is there a way to use `grep` or other commands to return the number line of a multiline pattern?

The format of the log is something like this in iterations of hundred thousands:

```
Packet A
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 01
ini_count   : 5

Packet F
op_3b       : 101
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 4

Packet X
op_3b       : 010
ctrl_2b     : 11
ini_count   : 98

Packet CA
op_3b       : 100
ctrl_2b     : 01
ini_count   : 5

Packet LP
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 0

Packet ZZ
op_3b       : 111
ctrl_2b     : 01
ini_count   : 545

Packet QEA
op_3b       : 111
ctrl_2b     : 11
ini_count   : 0
```

And what I am trying to get is to have `grep` or some other command to return the start of the line number of when these three line pattern occurs:

```
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that pattern is in file `pattern` like this:

```
$ cat pattern
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 0
```

Then, try:

```
$ awk '$0 ~ pat' RS=  pat="$(cat pattern)" logfile
Packet LP
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 0
```

#### How it works

- `RS=`

  This sets the Record Separator `RS` to an empty string.  This tells awk to use an empty line as the record separator.
- `pat="$(cat pattern)"`

  This tells awk to create an awk variable `pat` which contains the contents of the file `pattern`.

  If your shell is bash, then a slightly more efficient form of this command would be `pat="$(<pattern)"`.  (Don't use this unless you are *sure* that your shell is bash.)
- `$0 ~ pat`

  This tells awk to print any record that matches the pattern.

  `$0` is the contents of the current record.  `~` tells awk to do a match between the text in `$0` and the regular expression in `pat`.

  (If the contents of `pattern` had any regex active characters, we would need to escape them.  Your current example does not have any so this is not a problem.)

#### Alternative style

Some people prefer a different style for defining awk variables:

```
$ awk -v RS=  -v pat="$(cat pattern)" '$0 ~ pat' logfile
Packet LP
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 0
```

This works the same.

#### Displaying line numbers

```
$ awk -F'\n' '$0 ~ pat{print "Line Number="n+1; print "Packet" $0} {n=n+NF-1}' RS='Packet'  pat="$(cat pattern)" logfile
Line Number=20
Packet LP
op_3b       : 001
ctrl_2b     : 00
ini_count   : 0
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yours also works quite well and is, if it is important, less format sensitive than mine..

Comment: I have tried it and it works as intended. Thanks. Is it possible to have `awk` return the line number of which the patten had occur?

Comment: This will get you the line number: `'++i && $0 ~ pat { print $0"\n\n"i*5-4 }'`

Comment: @AlphonsevonAlexandric I just added a version to the answer that keeps track of line numbers.   Rafael's version in the comment above, which assumes 5 lines per entry, also works.

Comment: You should mention that the version to get line numbers requires GNU awk for multi-char RS. All versions will interpret escape sequences so for example `\t` in `pattern` will be converted to a literal tab in `pat` for matching against the input file and so wouldn't match if `\t` existed in the input. They'll also interpret RE metachars as such so `.` will match any char, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my scant attempt:

```
awk -v RS="" -v FS="\n" -v op=001 -v ctrl=00 -v ini=0 '$2~op&&$3~ctrl&&$4~ini' data.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The best approach so far is the one from [John1024](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3030305/john1024) using `awk` as you can do it in one pass, if you do really want to go for a `grep` solution, you can use:

```
$ grep -m 1 -zoP 'Packet\s*[^\s]*\s*(?=op_3b\s*:\s*001\s*ctrl_2b\s*:\s*00\sini_count\s*:\s*0)' file
Packet LP
```

**Notes:**

- `-m 1` will make grep return after the first match, you can remove it if your pattern appears several times.
- `-z` allows multi-lines patterns as it enables the `ASCII NUL` char instead of the normal EOL
- `-o` to just display the result match as output and not the whole file
- `-P` to activate perl regex

If you want to have the line number(s):

```
grep -n -f <(grep -m 1 -zoP 'Packet\s*[^\s]*\s*(?=op_3b\s*:\s*001\s*ctrl_2b\s*:\s*00\sini_count\s*:\s*0)' file) file
21:Packet LP
```

However you need to do 2 passes, so on a 15GB file `awk` is the best approach.

Comment: I didn't realize grep had a multiline flag (I've always used sed's `N`). That's cool!

Comment: @Rafael: Yeah it is a great option, but as far as I know it is only available for GNU grep: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Output-Line-Prefix-Control.html

Answer (score 0):

if your data in 'd' file try:

```
grep -nEA2 '^op_3b\s*:\s*001' d
```

edit number `001` above as your key search